# Bash script that can seamlessly call a windows EXE without having to call cygpath on each filename argument

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

I have several programs that instead of installing natively on Cygwin, I am going to use cygstart + cygpath to seamlessly utilize the Windows installation of those programs instead.

Examples: Gedit, Subversion 1.6.1, etc.

We would of course just use the Cygwin installer to install these natively... however, we have some pesky requirements:

1) Custom prefix location, for example the Cygport for GEdit will install it at `/usr/bin/gedit.exe` instead of `/common/web/bin/gedit.exe` that we need.

2) We need a version that isn't easily accessible from any cygwin repositories.

So I install the windows installer version of the product, then create a bash script that transparently calls the Windows program. Example: `/common/web/bin/gedit` is a bash script that will call `c:\apps\gedit\gedit.exe`

The problem is, you can't just run `cygpath -w` on each parameter. You have to be able to **only parse the filename arguments.** This basically requires going into the source code for each project, finding the `int main(int argc, char** argv)` and then reverse engineering how each filename can be parsed out.

Has anyone done this before? I'd love to see some examples of how you did it with a bash script or C++ program.

Comment: I don't think you are going to find a completely general solution.  The best you can hope for is one that works for your use case for the specific utilities you're interested in.  The question becomes: is it less of a pain to create and maintain those scripts than to install the cygwin versions in addition to the native versions.

Comment: See my self-answer for this question. You were correct and I used that to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After just a little bit more experimentation, I have found that this is a self-created problem.

My problem was I was trying to wrap the Windows native code with my own .sh file. Which then didn't let Cygwin automatically do it's magic of path conversion to the write platform.

For svn 1.6.1, here is what I did to fix this issue:

1. Installed svn at `c:\apps\svn\1.6.1\`
2. Run `ln -s /cygdrive/c/apps/svn/1.6.1/bin/svn.exe /common/web/bin/svn.exe`
3. Repeat step 2 for all the SVN exe's.
4. At this point, `/common/web/bin/svn.exe` works as if it is part of Cygwin! Amazing!